# Crystal Reports Year Selecton

Tags: crystal-reports, date-range

I'm using Crystal Reports 2011 and have a crosstab that's displaying data by YEAR (Row) and MONTH (Column).  I need to report 3 years worth of data at any given time but in the month of April is when I would need to drop an older year to pick up a newer year.

For example, currently since we are in February I am reporting 2010, 2011 and 2012.  Once April 1st hits I will be reporting 2011, 2012, and 2013.  So I will be dropping 2010 and picking up 2013 on the report.  I am looking to automate this so the report will automatically change the years that it reports.

I've tried various record selection formulas but have not been able to nail down one that returns the desired years.  The years are currently adjusted manually. On April 1st each year I manually adjust the report to drop 3 years prior and begin including current year data.

I'm looking for suggestions on how I can go about this.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: If the report were run right now, it would report on January 1st 2010 through February 12th 2012, and if the report were run April 1st, it would report January 1st 2011 through April 1st 2013?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes currently the report would display January 1st 2010 through February 12th, 2012.  On April first it will continue to report January 2010.  I have to go in manually to drop year 2010 and add year 2013.  My report displays 3 years of data at any given time and April 1st is when I drop the historical year which is 3 years prior (2010) and start reporting the current year 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I misstated the appropriate date ranges in my comments, but if I understand this correctly, we need formulas to do the following:

- if run today, the report will show data from 1/1/2010 to 12/31/2012.
- if run on April 1st, it will show data from 1/1/2011 to 4/1/2013.

To do this, I came up with the followign formula fields:

- Create a formula field called `DateRangeFrom`.  It should contain:

  ```
  IF datepart("m", CurrentDate) < 4 THEN

      // Show three years back if we are in the months January - March
      DateSerial (Year(DateAdd("yyyy", -3, CurrentDate)), 1, 1)
  ELSE
      // Show two years back if we are in the months of April - December
      DateSerial (Year(DateAdd("yyyy", -2, CurrentDate)), 1, 1)
  ```
- Create another formula called `DateRangeTo`.  It should contain:

  ```
  IF datepart("m", CurrentDate) < 4 THEN

      // Show one year back if we are in the months January - March
      DateSerial (Year(DateAdd("yyyy", -1, CurrentDate)), 12, 31)
  ELSE
      // Show up to the current date if we are in the months of April - December
      CurrentDate
  ```
- You can then use these fields in your record selection formula, like this:

  ```
  {YourTable.YourDateColumn} > {@DateRangeFrom} 
      AND {YourTable.YourDateColumn} <= {@DateRangeTo}
  ```

**EDIT:**

If you just want to search by the year, remove the `DateSerial` functions, and change your record selection formula to use `>=` instead of `>`, and you should be left with:

- Create a formula field called `DateRangeFrom`.  It should contain:

  ```
  IF datepart("m", CurrentDate) < 4 THEN

      // Show three years back if we are in the months January - March
      Year(DateAdd("yyyy", -3, CurrentDate))
  ELSE
      // Show two years back if we are in the months of April - December
      Year(DateAdd("yyyy", -2, CurrentDate))
  ```
- Create another formula called `DateRangeTo`.  It should contain:

  ```
  IF datepart("m", CurrentDate) < 4 THEN

      // Show one year back if we are in the months January - March
      Year(DateAdd("yyyy", -1, CurrentDate))
  ELSE
      // Show up to the current date if we are in the months of April - December
      Year(CurrentDate)
  ```
- You can then use these fields in your record selection formula, like this:

  ```
  {YourTable.YourDateColumn} >= {@DateRangeFrom} 
      AND {YourTable.YourDateColumn} <= {@DateRangeTo}
  ```

Comment: This looks great!  I added the formulas as you suggested but it didn't return any values and I'm almost certain it's because the year is stored as a 4 digit character year as the data is coming from SQL server.  I've tried converting everything to text and that didn't work and haven't had any luck converting my character year in crystal to a date without getting the bad date format error message.

Comment: What exactly are you searching against?  A four-digit year code, a full date, or something concatenated together?

Comment: Your updated suggestion worked perfectly!  Thank you so  much for your help!  My report is working as I hoped it would.